# problem with VGA output on HP elite Book 840 G3 running ubuntu 16.04

Tags: hp, vga

I have recently bought a HP Elite book 840 G3 and installed Linux/ubuntu 16.04. Everything works properly except one thing which is really problematic for me : the VGA output does not work and I am not able to get any image of the computer. I have tested it on more tan 20 videoprojector and I get only one case where I can send the image to videoprojector, all other cases nothing was possible. On the other hand, as I have also Windows seven installed on a double boot, everything worked out properly with windows. 
Is there a known incompatibility in the graphic card or whatever works for the VGA output with Linux/Ubuntu 16.04 ? Is there a way to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Cyril

Comment: please give us the output of `sudo lshw -c display`

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded the kernel as recommended in the following post:
[HP Elitebook 840 G3 Monitor Issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763320/hp-elitebook-840-g3-monitor-issue)

I have tried on a videoprojector where I had no signal before
and it works ! I think this give the solution (I will try on several other videoprojector to be 100% sure...)

best

Cyril